# What is "schlagen" slang for?

Tags: verb, slang

I had a German exchange student in my class and he always used "schlagen" in a weird way and it was hard to understand him. I know "schlagen" means "to fight" in English but what does it mean in German slang?

Comment: We may need some context from the usage of *"schlagen"* to tell.

Comment: Actually, *schlagen* doesn't exactly mean *to fight*, but *to hit* oder *to beat* (though *sich schlagen* does mean *to fight*: "Die beiden schlugen sich eine Stunde lang.")

Comment: It can also mean "to beat" as in "I beat him at chess."

Comment: Yeah, bot right. [And fifteen other things](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schlagen).

Comment: More animal brutality: "Die Amsel schlägt im Wald". You can "Haken schlagen" or "jemanden ein Schnippchen schlagen". If you need to stay awake, you can say "ich schlage mir die Nacht um die Ohren". If something is unexpected, you might hear "Jetzt schlägt es dreizehn!". There is a well known epitaph: "Hier liegt Martin Krug, der Kinder, Weib und Orgel schlug"

Comment: I'm surprised by "Denglish" which is used in comments!

Comment: @ Gigili: Yes, this schlägt dem barrel the Boden aus!

Comment: Is it by any chance possible that you (John) made the mistake to ignore the final little preposition? A lot of beginners and even more advanced speakers tend to do that when they don't have much everyday practice... so maybe there was a little "vor" somewhere or "ab" or "nach". Ain't gon' give no translations here :)

Comment: Er schlägt nach seinem Vater -> He looks/behaves much like his father. Er schlägt etwas vor -> He suggests something. Quite the versatile word, and more proof that your question is impossible to answer without context.

Comment: -1 because John had one week to provide some examples but instead keeps letting us guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to mention all different usages of this verb I found in dictionary.

***transitive verb***

1. (= zuschlagen, prügeln) to hit
2. (= hauen) to beat
      (mit der flachen Hand) to slap , to smack
      (mit der Faust) to punch
      (mit Hammer, Pickel etc)  Loch to knock

> - Die Bombe **schlug** ein Loch in die Straße (the bomb blew a hole in
>     the  road)
> - Jdn bewusstlos **schlagen** (to knock sb out)
> - Mit vielen **Schlägen** (to beat sb unconscious)
> - etw in Stücke or kurz und klein **schlagen** (to smash sth up or to pieces)
> - nach jdm/etw **schlagen** (to lash out at sb/sth)
> - um sich **schlagen** to lash out
> - mit dem Hammer auf den Nagel **schlagen** to hit the nail with the hammer
> - mit der Faust an die Tür/auf den Tisch **schlagen** to beat on the door/table with one's fist
> - gegen die Tür **schlagen** to hammer on the door
> - jdm or rare  jdn auf die Schulter **schlagen** (to slap sb on the back , (leichter) to pat sb on the back)
> - jdm etw aus der Hand **schlagen** (to knock sth out of sb's hand)
> - jdm or rare  jdn ins Gesicht schlagen (to hit/slap/punch sb in the face)
> - einer Sache  (dative)  ins Gesicht **schlagen**  figurative (to be a slap in the face for sth)
> - na ja, ehe ich mich **schlagen** lasse! (I suppose you could twist my arm - humorous informal)

1. (= läuten) to chime  Stunde to strike

   > - eine geschlagene Stunde (a full hour)
2. (= heftig flattern) mit den Flügeln schlagen (to beat its wings)

***intransitive verb***

Herz, Puls to beat    (heftig) to pound

> - Sein Puls **schlug** unregelmäßig (his pulse was irregular)
> - Ihr Herz **schlägt** für den FC Bayern (she's passionate about FC Bayern)

(auxiliary 'sein' or 'haben')(= auftreffen) mit dem Kopf auf/gegen

> etw  (accusative)  **schlagen** to hit one's head on/against sth

Regen to beat
    Wellen to pound
    Blitz to strike (in etw (accusative)  sth)

(auxiliary 'sein' or 'haben')

> - Er **schlägt** sehr nach seinem Vater (he takes after his father a lot)

***reflexive verb***

1. (= sich prügeln) to fight
   (= sich duellieren) to duel (auf (dative)  with)

> - sich um etw **schlagen** - literal  figurative (to fight over sth)
> - er **schlägt** sich nicht um die Arbeit (he's not crazy about work - informal)
> - sich tapfer or gut **schlagen** (to make a good showing)
> - sich auf jds Seite  (accusative)  **schlagen** (to side with sb , (=
>     die Fronten wechseln) to go over to sb)

Comment: Welches davon ist jetzt Slang?

Comment: @userunknown: There are many slang meaning along with the lines of my messages, stop downvoting what you do not know, I'll report this.

Comment: +1 for a very thorough answer.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: Nur leider alles Hochdeutsch.

Answer (score 2):

A few more non-trivial meanings of `schlagen` (depending on context) could be:

- *an einem Ort aufschlagen*: Which means to arrive somewhere
- *im Wesen nach jmd. schlagen*: Which means to figuratively follow somebodies steps, to have a similar character.
- *schlagend*: Which refers to [academic fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_fencing) and could be relevant, depending on what kind of class you are talking about (a class in an university or a school-class). A fraternity (Verbindung) is called *schlagend* if it still employs (maybe optional) academic fighting (although every fibre in me rejects to the translation of this with "academic", but that's what it's called). In this context, *schlagen* means to hit your opponent with a fencing sword in the face.

Comment: Keins davon ist Slang, oder?

Comment: @userunknown: Kommt drauf an, was man als Slang auffasst.

Comment: Die Spannung steigt ...

Comment: @userunknown: Ich fürchte, sie wird weiter steigen, da OP bereits eine Antwort angenommen hat, und keine Anstalten macht das Rätsel aufzulösen. Das meintest Du doch, oder?

Comment: Aufschlagen fuer "ankommen" ist schon Slang, wenn man jetzt nicht gerade von Projektilen spricht. War es vor 20 Jahren zumindest. Ich geh mal Wasser abschlagen.

Answer (score 1):

There are some more context-dependent meanings which have not been addressed:

- especially in student life, the context may be "schlagende Verbindung" which is a student association where the members actively practice fencing with an Épée (even with the possibility to gain some injuries in the face)
- "jemandem eine Bitte abschlagen" means "to reject somebody's plea"
- "ein Angebot ausschlagen" means "to reject an offer"

Comment: Und welches davon stufst Du als Slang ein? Alle drei?

Comment: Keines davon ist Slang, aber es sind meiner Meinung nach eher untypische Verwendungen.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question "what is schlagen slang for".

Comment: The author said "used in a weird way". So I think this is a better answer then the others because it adresses some unusual uses of the word "schlagen".

Answer (score 1):

Yiddish has quite a few meanings depending on the prefix.

*derschlagen sich zu...* means to reach your destination with some effort.

*derschlagen* as an adjective means depressed or dejected.

*vorschlagen* (as in German) means to suggest or propose.

*ausschlagen* can mean to cover as in "to cover your expenses". It can also mean to knock out.

*unterschlagen* means to line a garment.

*uberschlagen* means to throw a cover on top of.

*abschlagen* means to repel or reflect; also, to dissuade. In the reflexive (with sich) it can mean to bounce off. An *Abschalg* can be a repercussion.

*beschlagen* can mean to upholster, to cover, or to break out in (a rash).

EDIT: I pulled these out of Weinreich's dictionary, but it seems Harkavey's earlier dictionary has many more expressions, which I'm going to try and list below. Here goes:

- *abschlagen dem mut* to break one's spirit

*er schlagt ab seine taynos* he refutes his arguments

*sie schlagt ihm ab vun gehen* she dissuades him from leaving

*abshlagen wasser* to urinate

*men schlagt ihm ab die tueren* they're beating his door down, he is in great demand

*Ausschlag* a breakout of pimples

*ausschlagen* to strike as a clock, to strike the hour in full

*aufshclagen zwei brettlach* to join two boards

*aufschlagen a tur* to break down a door

*aufschlagen a wort* to seek the right word

*aufschlagen a summe* to collect a sum

*Umschlag* envelope, wrapper

*unterschlagen die augen* to give someone a black eye

*unterschlagen die parnosseh* to ruin someone's business by undercutting him; to embezzle money

*uberschlagen* to interrupt someone

*uberschlagen mit eier* to mix with eggs

*a dunner hat ihm eingeschlagen* he was struck by a thunderbolt

*anschlagen* to give someone a licking; to secure something to

*sich anschlagen* to offer one's services

*nehmen in  beschlag* to seize

*durchschlagen* to force one's way through

*sich herausschlagen vun kop* to forget about

*heraufschlagen* to fasten by beating; to fasten by nailing

*sich heraufschlagen* to get out of bed

*sich herumschlagen* to fight

*herunterschlagen* to beat down

*hereinschlagen* to drive in (a nail)

*derschlagen* to beat to death

*verschlagen* to fasten with nails

*zerschlagen* to break to pieces

*zunaufschlagen, zusammenschlagen* to fasten together

Comment: Youse forgettin da most important of dem all: **FERSHLUGINER!** A refresher course with Messrs. Drucker, Martin, and Jaffee is indicated, methinks.

Comment: Touchee. I missed the Mad Magazine reference. Of course, this is a made up word, and Weinreich's dictionary does not include a listing for VERSCHLAGEN. So I was surprised to find on checking with Harkavey that it is indeed a real word; it means to nail something up, to secure by nailing. It turns out that Harkavey has a far more extensive listing of usages for SHLAGEN in all its forms, so I'm going to put them up as an edit to my previous answer.

Comment: Interesting! In contemporary German we still have [*"Verschlag"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Verschlag) for a small room (nailed with boards), [*"verschlagen"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verschlagen_listig_raffiniert_gerissen) for *sly*, and [*"verschlagen"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verschlagen_schlagen_versperren_mischen) used in some dialects for *"to beat someone up"*.

Comment: Yiddish does seem to go to town with the prefixes. The dictionary only gave me the stuff about nails for VERSCHLAGEN but I took a look online and found yet another meaning in this quote from Sholom Aleichem, talking about the effect of penny-romances on the female reader: "...as ihr kop is verschlagen mit fantazyes..." (that her head is stuffed with nonsense".